# d3 Selecting data from an svg element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Having a problem in selecting the g elements in my d3 code and can't figure out how to do it.

**The Code**

```
var vis = d3.select("#custom-view").append('svg:svg').attr('width', w).attr('height', h);

d3.range(lengthJson).forEach(function (t) {
         vis.append("g")
         .attr('width', wBlob)
         .attr('height', hBlob);

          return t

});

var blobs = **tried numerous things here**.selectAll('g').data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        (....do a lot more code...)
```

**The Problem**

The code depicted above adds  elements into the  element depending on the length of the JSON file. Then I want it to append  elements to each  element inside that.

**Things I have Tried**

Tried to declare it a variable

```
var gCode = vis.append("g")
```

which works if it is not wrapped in the forEach function when making the g elements

I tried to assign a class in the attribute and select by all the g elements that way.

Also tried giving the svg element an ID and selecting it that way but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not** use loops, like `forEach`, to append elements in a D3 code.

Of course we use loops (`for` loops, `for...in` loops, `forEach` loops etc...) all the time in a D3 code, since D3 is JavaScript... but we don't use a loop to append elements, that's not the idiomatic way. Eventually we use loops to append elements, but in very specific and rare cases.

Using loops to append elements in a D3 code is not only awkward, but sometimes it will put you in a situation without (an easy) solution. Like this one.

The idiomatic way in your case is **nesting enter selections**.

So, use an enter selection to append your groups, based on the length of your data set, and then use an inner enter selection to append your rectangles, or whatever element you want.

Here is a very basic example, using `<div>`s  and `<tspan>`s:

```js
var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var body = d3.select("body");
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
var divs = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(data.length))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return colors(d)
  });
var texts = divs.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("tspan")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d + " "
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In the demo above, the `data` array has 3 elements. Thus, the first (or outer) enter selection will append 3 divs in the body.

Then, the second (inner) selection will append, for each div, the 3 elements in the data array.